# Understanding the Term \\\"$$PWD/\\\" in qmake project file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, pwd, projects-and-solutions

I found this line in a qmake project file:

> ```
> DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"
> ```

I know that the `PWD`-part stands for *print working directory* and I let 
give me the value of `SRCDIR`:

> ```
> std::cout << "SRCDIR :" << SRCDIR << std::end;
> ```

I also changed the variable to `SRCDIR=$$PWD` but it will not work.

But why we need a slash `/`, backslahses `\` and quotation marks `"` to get the `PWD`?

Comment: ...because qmake is broken when it comes to quoting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qmake` will handle quote characters and backslashes specially.

Your end goal is to have a string literal defined to be the expansion of `SRCDIR`. String literals in C++ are contained within double quotes, so you need those quotes to make it through to the compiler as part of the definition.

In other words, you want the equivalent of:

```
#define SRCDIR "somedir/"
```

where `somedir` is the current working directory, in this example. To achieve this, you want to escape the quote (so it isn't handled specially by `qmake`) using `\"`. This stands at both ends of the string.

Now, what about the escaped backslash, `\\`? Well, this further escapes the quote from shell processing. When the command

```
cc -DSRCDIR="somedir/"
```

is passed to the shell, the quotes will be stripped as part of the shell's processing. To make sure those quotes remain, and define a string literal, you need to escape them with a backslash at this level, too. The shell will convert `\"` into `"`. So the full escape sequence for a double quote character in this case is:

```
\\\"
```

This token appears at both ends of the defined string. The forward-slash just makes it easier to use the path inside the code; it eliminates the need to add a `/` everywhere you use the path.

The command that the shell sees will look like

```
cc -DSRCDIR=\"somedir/\"
```

and the definition of `SRCDIR` inside the compiler will be a string literal, equivalent to the following definition in-source:

```
#define SRCDIR "somedir/"
```